# How to compare two given times with current time?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

I want to compare current time with two different times on different dates.MY code is

```
NSString *time1 = record.trigger_from_time;
NSString *time2 = record.trigger_to_time;

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];

NSDate *date1= [formatter dateFromString:time1];
NSDate *date2 = [formatter dateFromString:time2];

NSLog(@"%@,%@",date1,date2);
```

I'm getting  log as 2000-01-01 09:12:00 +0000,2000-01-01 12:30:00 +0000

But MY current time is 2014-04-01 17:06:18.

I'm getting current date from

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date]; 
NSDateFormatter *timeFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; 
timeFormatter.dateFormat = @"HH:mm"; 
[timeFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]]; 
NSLog(@"The Current Time is %@",[timeFormatter stringFromDate:now]);
```

I want to compare thie current time with record.trigger_from_time and record.trigger_to_time

Comment: I am not sure what your question has to do with the code you posted

Comment: what is record.trigger_from_time? and what is record.trigger_to_time?

Comment: I want to get date1 and date2 time as time with current date.I can do coparision but date is showing as 2000-01-01 not getting current date.

Comment: Can you share the code where you get the current date as record.trigger_from_time isn't the current date unless you are setting that somewhere else this looks like something from an object

Comment: record.trigger_from_time and record.trigger_to_time are time string coming from Json Api.record.trigger_from_time="18:00:00" and record.trigger_to_time= "06:07:00"

Comment: I'm getting current date from NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
                    
                    NSDateFormatter *timeFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
                    timeFormatter.dateFormat = @"HH:mm";
                    [timeFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
                    NSLog(@"The Current Time is %@",[timeFormatter stringFromDate:now]);

I want to compare thie current time with record.trigger_from_time and record.trigger_to_time

Comment: You need to get everything on the same page (of the calendar).  Either convert current time to Day 1 or convert your timestamps to today.  (Or better still, save the timestamps as valid NSDate values to begin with.)

Comment: Hint:  Someone who was fairly skilled at Objective-C could avoid it, but use NSCalendarComponents to separate your values and recombine them so everything is on the same day.  Will be more than a few lines, but it's straight-forward code.

Comment: Oops, I mean "NSDateComponents".

Comment: please provide some code with NSCalendarComponents.I'm very new to this technology.

Comment: please provide some code with NSDateComponents.I'm very new to this technology

Comment: Google it.  And look at the spec.  (You do know how to find the spec, right?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparing 2 NSDates.

```
    ...
    NSDate *date1= [formatter dateFromString:time1];
    NSDate *date2 = [formatter dateFromString:time2];

    if ([date2 compare:date1] == NSOrderedDescending) {
        NSLog(@"date1 is later than date2");

    } else if ([date2 compare:date1] == NSOrderedAscending) {
        NSLog(@"date1 is earlier than date2");

    } else {
        NSLog(@"dates are the same");

    }
```

UPD:
via Switch

```
       ...
        NSDate *date1= [formatter dateFromString:time1];
        NSDate *date2 = [formatter dateFromString:time2];

        NSComparisonResult result = [date2 compare:date1];
        switch(result){
            case NSOrderedDescending:
                NSLog(@"date1 is later than date2");
                break;
            case NSOrderedAscending:
                NSLog(@"date1 is earlier than date2");
                break;
            default:
                NSLog(@"dates are the same");
                break;
         }
```

Comment: Of course, one need only do one compare, and either save the result in a temp or use a `switch`.

Comment: @HotLicks sure, it's more better

Comment: Its failing when i compare current time with two given times(date format is: HH:mm). it shows dates are the same.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString *time1 = @"09:10:02";
NSString *time2 = @"17:10:16";

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:"];

NSDate *date1= [formatter dateFromString:time1];
NSDate *date2 = [formatter dateFromString:time2];

NSComparisonResult result = [date1 compare:date2];
if(result == NSOrderedDescending)
{
     NSLog(@"time1 is later than time2"); 
}
else if(result == NSOrderedAscending)
{
     NSLog(@"time2 is later than time1"); 
}
else
{
     NSLog(@"time1 is equal to time2");
}
```

Comment: I hope this answer will be the right to your question.......