# How do you compare current time with specified times (to determine Open/Closed)?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I´m making an app for different nightclubs and pubs, and I want to add the opening and closing times of those nightclubs and pubs. How do I check if the current time on the users iPhone is within the opening hours or not?

For example with opening hours 22-03 / 10PM-3AM:
current time 22:01  -> Open
current time 03:01 -> Closed

Sorry if I didn´t make the question clear enough, but I would appreciate any answer =)

Comment: Something like this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20440333/compare-current-time-and-compare-it-with-two-nsstring-time-in-objective-c ?

Comment: Read the doc for NSDate, NSDateFormatter, NSCalendar, and NSDateComponents.  There are easily 5 different ways to do what you want.

Comment: Xcode is an IDE / design environment; don't confuse it with the Objective-C language or applicable runtime

Comment: Might be relevant as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22784748/how-to-compare-two-given-times-with-current-time-in-ios?lq=1

Comment: Being lazy, what I would do is arrange the times as 24-hour times such as "22:30", use NSDateFormatter to format the current time with "HH:mm", and perform string compares.  (Others would use elaborate NSDateComponents thingies.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have mentioned there are different ways of doing this and you should be referencing the Apple documentation for how to use NSDate and the various other classes used with working with dates.

But to quickly help out, I haven't tried this (I just wrote it directly in the text box), but this should work for you. You would use a comparison to see if the current time was less than or greater than another time:

```
NSDate* openTime...;
NSDate* closeTime...
NSDate* now = [NSDate date];

NSComparisonResult result = [openTime compare:now];

if(result == NSOrderedDescending)
{
    NSLog(@"Now takes place before the opening time."); 
}
else if(result == NSOrderedAscending)
{
    NSLog(@"Now takes place after the opening time."); 
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Now and opening time are the same.");
}


result = [closeTime compare:now];

if(result == NSOrderedDescending)
{
    NSLog(@"Now takes place before the closing time."); 
}
else if(result == NSOrderedAscending)
{
    NSLog(@"Now takes place after the closing time."); 
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Now and closing time are the same.");
}
```

Comment: The problem with that is that NSDate represents a specific day, so you have to re-calculate the opening and closing times daily.

Comment: I have to get to the cafe before it closes here at work but I'll update my answer for time only when I get back.

Comment: Naw, that closing time is for last week.